# how retrieve AbpSession in a MVC view

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

someone know how to retrieve the ApbSession in a mvc view??

i've tried with a session, or accessing the controllers that have the session injected, but there's no way to get the currentSession to get the userId and other properties.

The Asp.net Session is not valid, because ApbSession dont work with it.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: What about adding to the ViewBag, or model? From your controlled (inherited from `YourApplicationControllerBase` that derived from `AbpController`) you have the AbpSession so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to get needed values in the controller then pass to the view via viewmodel. However, if you need to access to AbpSession you have different ways depending on the ASP.NET version you are using.

For ASP.NET Core, use `@inject IAbpSession AbpSession` in the razor view and directly use it.

For ASP.NET MVC 5.x, use property injection in your view base (YourProjectNameWebViewPageBase like that: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template/blob/master/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.WebMpa/Views/AbpProjectNameWebViewPageBase.cs). Alternatively, you can use `IocManager.Instance.Resolve<IAbpSession>()...` wherever you need.

Comment: Thanks so much. i've tried to inyect the session in the **WebViewPageBase, but in the Mvc View the session is "null", i dont know if im doing something wrong...

I will try resolving the service in the view, or passing by the ViewBag...

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion of [hikalkan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45266007/752004) above, here it is the code to add it in class `[YourApplication]WebViewPageBase<TModel>`:

```cs
public abstract class YourAppWebViewPageBase<TModel> : AbpWebViewPage<TModel>
{
    // Gp
    public IAbpSession AppSession { get; private set; }

    protected YourAppWebViewPageBase()
    {
        LocalizationSourceName = YourAppConsts.LocalizationSourceName;
        // Gp - added the AbpSession in the view
        AppSession = Abp.Dependency.SingletonDependency<IAbpSession>.Instance;
    }
}
```